# Why does iframe scrolling not work on mobile Safari?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, iframe, mobile-safari

iFrames inside fixed height block elements won't scroll on iOS devices...

About once a year, I'll encounter this issue while testing something I made on an iPhone or iPad. I have a moment of confusion / frustration, then I remember "Oh yeah... this STILL doesn't work."

**My question today is WHY is this?**

In case it's not clear, I already know that you can't scroll iframes within fixed / absolute position divs and I'm not asking for work-arounds (those are well documented elsewhere). What I want to know is **why**. After 3 years or so, it doesn't really feel like a bug anymore. Does Apple want it to be this way? Did Uncle Steve hate iframes almost as much as Flash? What's going on with this?